# ODBC - Get DB2 user tables

Tags: c#, .net, db2, odbc

In my .NET app, I am using ODBC driver to connect to DB2 database.

I want to show to my user what table he can access using provided credentials - and I want to read tables and columns from database.

I have found I can call

```
conn.GetSchema("TABLES", { null, "UserName", null });
```

but this returns tables that are in schema called "UserName", not those I can access as this user.

I am new to DB2 databases, can I somehow do it, for example by querying some system tables containing privileges? Can I do it with non-admin credentials?

Comment: What operating-system runs the Db2-server ( Z/OS,  i-series, or  Linux/Unix/Windows)?  (you need to know this).

Comment: Right now it's Win 7 - but eventually I should not assume any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each platform of Db2 (Z/OS, i-series,  Linux/Unix/Windows/cloud) has different schemas for their catalog.  The online Knowledge-Centres per platform and version detail the catalog views and tables.

I am not sure if any ODBC generic functions exist for your specific requirement.

For Db2-server for Linux/Unix/Windows you can either query the [SYSCAT.TABAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001061.html) view and related views (if you have access, which is the default), or you can call a stored procedure [AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0052898.html) and process its output.

For Db2-for-Z/OS, you can query [SYSIBM.SYSTABAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystabauthtable.html) and related tables, subject to your access and local site rules.

For Db2 for i, you can query [QSYS2.SYSTABAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatsystabauth.htm) and related tables, subject to your access and local site rules.